# GParted LiveCD - Cannot resize partition

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, gparted

I'm using the latest GParted live CD and I am trying to re-size a partition on which the latest version of Ubuntu is installed.

/dev/sda contains a linux swap partition and a partition that has the Ubuntu installation on it.

Whenever I click 're-size' on where the Ubuntu installed is installed, I cannot do it, as all the arrows are grayed out.

I have un-mounted and deactivated the drive to no avail, and tried booting the live CD from  the CD as well as the RAM.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You have to deactive swap with `# swapoff -a` and if does not help paste more texts or screenshots.